# How to run OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown from external class

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

Hello i have a couple of test classes on which i am using the same resource that i `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown`  which is `IEmbeddable`.

Lets say i have `N` testclasses that in which i want to reuse the `OneTimeSetUp`,`OneTimeSetDown` and a resource (an interface `IEmbeddedable`) .How can i create a static  class `EmbeddableController` that can be reused by all testclasses?

Basically i want to :

```
-Start static Resource of type `IEmbeddedable` once
-Run TestClass 1 on resource ( set it up +tear it down)
-Run TestClass 2 on resource (set it up + tear it down)
......
-Run TestClass N on resource (set it up +tear it down)
```

**IEmbeddedable**

```
interface IEmbeddedable:IDisposable {
        int ExposedPort { get; }
    }
```

**Test_ClassX**

```
class Test_ClassX {
            private IEmbeddedable server;
            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public  void Launch() {
                server = RedisServer.Launch();
            }
            [OneTimeTearDown]
            public void Stop() {
                this.server.Dispose();
            }

            [TestCase()]
            public async Task CanRunEmbeddedServer() {

                using (server) {
                    var multi = new Multiplexer();
                    using (var link = multi.OpenLink(Address.Create(Port:server.ExposedPort))) {
                        string rez=await link.FlushAllAsync();
                        Assert.AreEqual(rez, "OK");
                    }


                }
            }
}
```

**Prototype**

```
 static class EmbeddedController {
        private static  IEmbeddedable server;
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void Run() {
            server = RedisServer.Launch();
        }
        public static void Stop() {
            server.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

How can i inject this last class in all testclasses?It can be static or not , either way it will be only one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneTimeSetUp` can run at various levels. On a `TestFixture`, it runs once for the fixture. On a SetUpFixture it runs once for the namespace. This gives you several options...

1. Have all your fixtures inherit from `EmbeddedController`. However, the `OneTimeSetUp` will then run once for each fixture. While it's possible to make a test and only initialize the server once, you will not have any way to know when the **last** test has run so that you can dispose of it. My conclusion is that this won't work for your case, although it would work for anything that holds no resources and so doesn't require disposal.
2. Put all the fixtures that require `EmbeddedController` into the same namespace, without any other classes. Put `EmbeddedController` into the same namespace and make it a `SetUpFixture`. The `OneTimeSetUp` will run once, before any of fixtures and the `OneTimeTearDown` will run  once, after all the fixtures have completed. In order for the fixtures to access the server, you should make `Server` a static property of `EmbeddedController`.